# vb.net - How would I replace GoTo in this instance?

Tags: vb.net, console, case, goto

GoTo used to return to menu after a case was carried out, since its bad practice to use GoTo what else could I do? Thanks.

```
Menu:
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------") 
            Console.WriteLine("1 = option1")
            Console.WriteLine("2 = option2")
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------")
            Console.Write("Select an option: ")
            opts = Console.ReadLine 
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------")
                Select Case opts
                    Case 1
Happening:
                        Try 
                            Console.Write("Enter a word: ")
                            word = Console.ReadLine 
                            Select Case word.ToLower  
                               Case Eng(0)
                                    Console.WriteLine(Fre(0))
                                Case Eng(1)
                                    Console.WriteLine(Fre(1))
                            GoTo Menu
                            End Select
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input")
                        End Try
```

Comment: Have you tried to create functions ?

Comment: @CamiloR Complete beginner here, so while I have tried certain loops and functions none have so far worked for me, although that's likely due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You may want to create a boolean.  And then set it to true when they enter somethnig good.       dim goodEntryExists as boolean = false.   while (goodEntryExists  = false ) (all your code)........and when they enter something you  like set goodEntryExists = true.  something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a boolean variable to control the exit from a while loop that encloses your code.

While the boolean variable is true you continue your loop reading the user input, processing it and reprinting the menu choices. Setting the boolean variable to false will terminate the loop.
Don't forget to offer an option to terminate the program

```
Dim runLoop = true
while runLoop
  Console.WriteLine("----------------------") 
  Console.WriteLine("1 = option1")
  Console.WriteLine("2 = option2")
  Console.WriteLine("3 = EXIT")
  Console.WriteLine("----------------------")
  Console.Write("Select an option: ")
  opts = Console.ReadLine 
  Console.WriteLine("----------------------")
  Select Case opts
      Case "1"
        Try 
           Console.Write("Enter a word: ")
           word = Console.ReadLine 
           Select Case word.ToLower  
               Case Eng(0)
                   Console.WriteLine(Fre(0))
               Case Eng(1)
                    Console.WriteLine(Fre(1))
                    runLoop = false
           End Select
       Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input")
       End Try           
      case "2"
           .....
      case "3"
           runLoop = false
    End Select
 End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code Below.

```
Dim goodResultExists As Boolean = False
While Not goodResultExists
 Console.Write("Enter a word: ")
                        word = Console.ReadLine 
                        Select Case word.ToLower  
                            case "Ok"
                            goodResultExists = True
                            Case Else
                            Console.Write("Invalid Entry")

                        End Select
End While
```